# Android: TextView: Remove spacing and padding on top and bottom

Tags: android, textview, padding, spacing

When I have a `TextView` with a `\n` in the text,, on the right I have two `singleLine` `TextView`s, one below the other with no spacing in between. I have set the following for all three `TextView`s.

```
android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1" 
android:lineSpacingExtra="0pt" 
android:paddingTop="0pt" 
android:paddingBottom="0pt"
```

The first line of the left `TextView` lines up perfectly with the top right `TextView`.

The second line of the left `TextView` is a little higher than the second line of the bottom right `TextView`.

It seems that there is some kind of hidden padding on the top and the bottom of the `TextView`s. How can I remove that?

Comment: try to set gravity of this textview to center_vertical

Comment: Hi,George Bailey, Do you have solution after so long time? I encounter this problem too now. Can you give me your solution? thanks.

Comment: @mmm2006, Been so long I don't know what I ended up doing. Try the solutions in the answers. If that doesn't work, make a new question.

Comment: This didn't work for me

Comment: any of below answers didnt work for me, can you help

Answer (score 630):

```
setIncludeFontPadding (boolean includepad)
```

or in `XML` this would be:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Set whether the `TextView` includes extra top and bottom padding to make room for accents that go above the normal ascent and descent. The default is true.

Comment: But it seems always has a `1dp` top/bottom padding, am i wrong?(I use `Developer options -> Show layout bounds`)

Comment: `includeFontPadding="false"` does remove some of the space, but not all of it.  very strange.

Comment: This can be a double edged sword. `includeFontPadding` is great for removing any additional padding from the font itself but it can cause issues  in languages that have ascenders and descenders. I would make sure if you do this that you test languages like spanish and thai if you support them.

Comment: android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp" (Optional) has worked for me.

Comment: After setting runtime it's not taking top padding but bottom padding still there, even left and right padding as well? any suggestion?

Comment: Pay attention because this will remove the padding needed to display some bottom parts of letters like "p", "y", g. These letters will be partially cut off.

Comment: For normal alphabets A-Z, a-z, includeFontPadding = false should work nicely. @mattblang The extra tiny bit of padding is reserved for things like $ sign. So includeFontPadding should work nicely for a standard english keyboard. But for foreign languages like a Chinese character, you might get into cropping problem.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I don't understand what I'm missing.  I still have unwanted space at the bottom of my TextView

Comment: @MartyMiller add a attribute on your textview, android:letterSpacing="0"

Comment: If you are seeking for something you will get it as long as you don't stop. I am feeling lucky. From the past few days I got mad and was thinking like if it was the problem of line height. Thanks!

Answer (score 50):

I searched a lot for proper answer but no where I could find an Answer which could exactly remove all the padding from the `TextView`, but finally after going through the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:includeFontPadding) got a work around for **Single Line Texts**

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
```

Adding these two lines to `TextView` xml will do the work.
First attribute removes the padding reserved for accents and second attribute removes the spacing reserved to maintain proper space between two lines of text.

> Make sure not to add `lineSpacingExtra="0dp"` in multiline TextView as it might make the appearance clumsy

Comment: adding these two line is not working for me and also there is no change in padding

Comment: @sunilkushwah, it will definitely work if you are doing it properly. Would be glad to help if you can provide more details about your problem.

Comment: @sunilkushwah You can probably push it on github and share the link

Comment: @sunilkushwah i see that you are using Brandon Font (Custom Font). Can you once try by removing `fontPath` attribute?

Comment: i tried this but its not working,Note :i don't want any default padding in TextView

Comment: What do you mean by **any default** padding? linespacing removes padding from bottom and fontpaddingexra removes the padding on top reserved for accents. What else do you want to remove?

Comment: means when i view my layout in auto layout bounds it will not show the white space around Textview.

Comment: Can you upload the picture of screenshot and send the link please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138884/discussion-between-sunil-kushwah-and-mohammed-atif).

Answer (score 42):

I feel your pain. I've tried every answer above, including the `setIncludeFontPadding` to false, which did nothing for me.

My solution?  `layout_marginBottom="-3dp"` on the `TextView` gives you a solution for the bottom,
BAM!

Although, -3dp on `layout_marginTop` fails....ugh.

Comment: This can lead to the bottom of the text potentially getting cut off

Comment: Really bad idea of use negative margin. Better to consider a custom view and draw the text exactly as you want.

Comment: If patch like this, you should calculate the ratio of font size too.

Answer (score 36):

You can try to use this attribute(ConstraintLayout):`layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf`

Like this:

> app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tnx. this also helped me in an other problem which there is a textview that has multisizeed text. with this solution I can use multiple textview with there different textsizes and with the help of base line constraints I can show them like its one textview.

Answer (score 29):

**Updated XML**

```
android:fontFamily="monospace"
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! When you answer a question you should include some kind of explanation, like what the author did wrong and what you did to fix it. I'm telling you this because your answer has been flagged as low-quality and is currently being reviewed. You can [edit] your answer by clicking the "Edit" button.

Comment: Actually changing android:fontFamily is not necessary if you already have correct font. Basicly android:includeFontPadding is the only thing necessary and it has been mentioned in previous answers from the thread.

Comment: @DarekDeoniziak Some fonts have spaces

Answer (score 21):

If you use [`AppCompatTextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatTextView) ( or from `API 28` onward ) you can use the combination of those 2 attributes to remove the spacing on the first line:

**XML**

```
android:firstBaselineToTopHeight="0dp"
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

**Kotlin**

```
text.firstBaselineToTopHeight = 0
text.includeFontPadding = false
```

Comment: same, not working. still extra padding on the top

Comment: This worked with the android parameter:layout_height="wrap_content"

Answer (score 20):

Add android:includeFontPadding="false" to see if it helps.And make text view size same as that of text size rather than "wrap content".It will definitely work.

Answer (score 14):

This annoyed me too, and the answer I found was that there is actually additional space in the font itself, not the TextView. It is rather irritating, coming from a document publishing background, the limited amount of control you have with Android over typographic elements. I'd recommend using a custom typeface (such as Bitstream Vera Sans, which is licensed for redistribution) that may not have this issue. I'm not sure specifically whether or not it does, though.

Comment: do you have some free font to point me to? I need to have no margin on top without assigning negative margins! Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

I remove the spacing in my custom view -- NoPaddingTextView.

https://github.com/SenhLinsh/NoPaddingTextView

[image]

```
package com.linsh.nopaddingtextview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Senh Linsh on 17/3/27.
 */

public class NoPaddingTextView extends TextView {

    private int mAdditionalPadding;

    public NoPaddingTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }


    public NoPaddingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setIncludeFontPadding(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int yOff = -mAdditionalPadding / 6;
        canvas.translate(0, yOff);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        getAdditionalPadding();

        int mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (mode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            int measureHeight = measureHeight(getText().toString(), widthMeasureSpec);

            int height = measureHeight - mAdditionalPadding;
            height += getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    private int measureHeight(String text, int widthMeasureSpec) {
        float textSize = getTextSize();

        TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
        textView.setText(text);
        textView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, 0);
        return textView.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    private int getAdditionalPadding() {
        float textSize = getTextSize();

        TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
        textView.setLines(1);
        textView.measure(0, 0);
        int measuredHeight = textView.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (measuredHeight - textSize > 0) {
            mAdditionalPadding = (int) (measuredHeight - textSize);
            Log.v("NoPaddingTextView", "onMeasure: height=" + measuredHeight + " textSize=" + textSize + " mAdditionalPadding=" + mAdditionalPadding);
        }
        return mAdditionalPadding;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post (and get up-votes). Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Subclassing from `TextView`  and especially overriding `onDraw` seems to me as a very bad idea. In such a way you will lose all the fancy decorations that Google does or will do in the future releases (and of course no features from the `AppCompat` as well) and you can't match OEM-specific style of this control on particular device if there is one.

Comment: I changed in a new way.

Comment: It may work but creating new TextView on every measure event is not memory efficient. Android Lint discourages creating new objects in draw(), onDraw() or any method that is related to layout and can be called unknown times during layout.

Answer (score 6):

Since my requirement is override the existing textView get from `findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("xxx", "id", "android"));`, so I can't simply try `onDraw()` of other answer.

But I just figure out the correct steps to fixed my problem, here is the final result from Layout Inspector:

[image]

Since what I wanted is merely remove the top spaces, so I don't have to choose other font to remove bottom spaces.

Here is the critical code to fixed it:

```
Typeface mfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/myCustomFont.otf");
myTextView.setTypeface(mfont);

myTextView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

myTextView.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
```

The first key is set custom font "fonts/myCustomFont.otf" which has the space on bottom but not on the top, you can easily figure out this by open otf file and click any font in android Studio:

[image]

As you can see, the cursor on the bottom has extra spacing but not on the top, so it fixed my problem.

The second key is **you can't simply skip any of the code**, otherwise it might not works. That's the reason you can found some people comment that an answer is working and some other people comment that it's not working.

Let's illustrated what will happen if I remove one of them.

Without `setTypeface(mfont);`:

[image]

Without `setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);`:

[image]

Without `setIncludeFontPadding(false);`:

[image]

Without 3 of them (i.e. the original):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/baselineImage"
        android:includeFontPadding="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/baselineImage"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <!-- This view will be exactly 10dp below the baseline of textView -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/baselineImage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

With an extra ImageView we can set the TextView to be baseline aligned with the ImageView and set the `android:baselineAlignBottom` on the ImageView to true, which will make the baseline of ImageView to bottom. Other views can align itself using the bottom of the ImageView which itself is the same as the TextView's baseline.

This however only fixes the padding bottom not the top.

Comment: perfect for my situation, way better than removing font padding. +1

Answer (score 3):

I think this problem can be solved in this way:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftText"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:text="Hello World!\nhello world" />

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightUpperText"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftText"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/leftText"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightLowerText"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rightUpperText"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:text="hello world" />
```

Those are the results:

[ScreenShot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGat1.png)

[ScreenShot-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2AoM.png)

Though the line of special characters in rightLowerText looks a little bit higher than the second line of leftText, their baselines are stilled aligned.

Comment: includeFontPadding="false" was exactly what I needed!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can partially resolve this with some of the hacks listed here (negative margins, font padding, etc), but you can't get around the size of the font itself[1]. The fixed height of each "cell" of a font must be large enough to accommodate the tallest character, *in all languages*.

If you employ the hacks listed in other answers the font may end up clipped.

The solution is to explain to your designers that this is how fonts are packaged, and to have them account for this in their designs. Don't hack things up now to have bugs filed down the road when it's translated to other languages and ascenders / descenders are clipped.

[1] I suppose one could package their own fonts with compacted ascenders and descenders.

Comment: I was really confused as to why these fonts always have padding but the UI designs don't. Thank you for bringing this aspect to light.

Answer (score 1):

Simple method worked:

```
setSingleLine();
setIncludeFontPadding(false);
```

If it not worked, then try to add this above that code:

```
setLineSpacing(0f,0f);
// and set padding and margin to 0
```

If you need multi line, maybe you'll need to calculate exactly the height of padding top and bottom via temp single line  TextView (before and after remove padding) , then apply decrease height result with negative padding or some Ghost Layout with translate Y. Lol

Answer (score 1):

Only thing that worked is

```
android:lineSpacingExtra="-8dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try aligning the bottom of the left text view with the bottom of the 2nd right text view.

Comment: But then the top line would not line up. And actually I do not care about them lining up as much as I would really like to remove the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this is inherent to most widgets and the amount of "padding" differs among phone manufacturers.  This padding is really white space between the image border and the image in the 9 patch image file.

For example on my Droid X, spinner widgets get extra white space than buttons, which makes it look awkward when you have a spinner inline with a button, yet on my wife's phone the same application doesn't have the same problem and looks great!

The only suggestion I would have is to create your own 9 patch files and use them in your application.

Ahhh the pains that are Android.

Edited: Clarify padding vs white space.

Answer (score 0):

This trick worked for me (for **min-sdk >= 18**).

I used `android:includeFontPadding="false"` and a **negative margin** like `android:layout_marginTop="-11dp"` and put my `TextView` inside a `FrameLayout` ( **or any ViewGroup...**)

[image]

and finally sample codes:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        style="@style/MyTextViews.Bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-11dp"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        tools:text="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This trick may not work for different font, sizes or layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Use constraintlayout as your root view then add a guideline helper.

Example:

```xml
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/textView1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/textView2"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
 android:id="@+id/guideline"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />
```

Attribute layout_constraintGuide_begin value is just example, it depend on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
android:minHeight="0dp"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32044921)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this attribute(ConstraintLayout): `layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf`

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference from the below XML file where the imageView will start from the bottom of baseline of the text of Textview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewHello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img_star_05"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewHello"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewHello"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textViewHello" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textViewHello"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Alternatively, assuming for most of your use cases you would need the bottom of your imageView to be aligned with the baseline, for that you can put the below code in your TextView.

```
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/imageViewHello"
```

Answer (score -1):

See this:

[Align ImageView with EditText horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372159/align-imageview-with-edittext-horizontally)

It seems that the background image of EditText has some transparent pixels which also add padding.

A solution is to change the default background of EditText to something else (or nothing, but no background for a EditText is probably not acceptable). That's can be made setting android:background XML attribute.

```
android:background="@drawable/myEditBackground"
```

Answer (score -1):

**It's working for me**

just add two lines to your Textview

> ```
>  android:includeFontPadding="false"
>  android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.8"
> ```

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/searchByItemTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:fontFamily="@font/dm_sans"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.8"
            android:paddingVertical="3dp"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="6dp"
            android:text="@string/date_of_birth"
            android:textColor="@color/text_black"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
```

note: don't use  `android:textAppearance=""`

Answer (score -9):

Use this in your ImageView xml

android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: Please add some explanation about that

Comment: i thought this must be understood. I can only be used in xml .