# Gravity being ignored over a certain textsize

Tags: android, fonts, textview, gravity

Am I missing something, if I just have a standard TextView and set its text size over a set number the gravity to center the text stops working, see below example.

Gravity working:

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="B"
    android:textSize="472sp" />
```

[image: Gravity working]

---

Gravity not working

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="B"
    android:textSize="572sp" />
```

[image: Gravity not working]

This happens on a device as well as the emulator / preview.

Comment: I think Bill Gates once remarked that `472sp` ought to be enough for anyone. :-)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8435 :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have guessed it's because the total size of the TextView including implicit padding (such as may exist) is simply larger than your screen, so the field is pinned at the top and the visible portion is forced down the screen.  What happens if you put it onto a bigger display?  Edit: In the 572sp example, it comes pretty close to centered in portrait mode on a tablet.

Comment: AH ok. Yeah putting it on a 5inch it's centered again. So the space around the letter 'B' I guess thats part of the font? Because my textviews padding is 0.

Comment: Did you apply custom styling to remove any padding that might have been in the parent style?

Comment: My guess is the font itself has no intrinsic padding, but maybe the text field does.

Comment: I stuck `android:padding="0dip"` on it with no effect, still that big gap down the left / top.

Comment: See for example attributes like android:includeFontPadding and android:lineSpacingExtra.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can also play dirty tricks like specifying negative padding.

Comment: Tried all those attributes with no effect. Only thing I could do is `layout_margin="-20dip"` but that number needs to be dynamic. This guy reckons there is padding in the font that makes the most sense at the moment : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4769205/413127