# TextView won't center vertically in parent

Tags: android, layout, textview

My activity has only a single TextView and I am trying to get the text to center vertically but it ends up aligning to the bottom. I tried changing several properties but no luck. Here is currently what I have (Android 2.3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llFlash"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFlash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**
I am actually setting the textsize in code and it is to a large value. If the textsize is increased to be the width of the screen (in landscape mode), then it appears aligned to the bottom of the screen. However, if you use a normal textsize (like 20sp), it will appear centered. This tells me that when you increase the textsize to be very large, it appears that Android is increasing some hidden inside padding (even though I did set includeFontPadding to false).

Comment: i tried your code,it looks fine.

Comment: If that's you whole layout then it's positioning correctly on my end.

Comment: Try Layout_gravity instead gravity. and remove layout_centerinparent.

Comment: How about in landscape mode? That's what I am using.

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine to me but,

why don't you use;

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

instead of

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a limitation not of the TextView but rather the way Android handles fonts with large text. Others have noticed this as well:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4769205/753632

Answer (score 0):

even without layout:gravity, it looks okay to me.

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

or

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

you may also modify your relative layout to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Since match_parent is more advisable starting from API 8.

Is this the only layout in the activity? or Is this part of a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

first, create another relative layout inside the main layout and then insert your textview inside, after that, set gravity property to center like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/llFlash"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:padding="0dp" >
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="3.5">
  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/ucontact"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:text="0708453589"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```