# Spacing between Child Items when Expand parent item

Tags: java, android

I have just created an expandable RecyclerView with different views as every parent item have a child My case is when expanding parent item it view it's child with a vertical spacing between each child Item like this
[image]

as this is my main XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#dedede"
        tools:context="abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.MainPaymentActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/checkNoET"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
                android:editable="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="505050505050"
                android:textSize="12dp">

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/checkNo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkNoET"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkNoET"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
                android:text="Check#"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkNoET"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkNoET"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/check" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkNoET"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkNoET"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:editable="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="5"
                android:textSize="12dp">

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                android:text="Coves"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/covers" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tableNo"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkNoET"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
                android:editable="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="25"
                android:textSize="12dp">

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tableNo"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tableNo"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkNo"
                android:text="Table"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkNoET"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/tablepay" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText14"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tableNo"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tableNo"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="15/10/2017 03:15PM"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText14"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText14"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/calendar" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/parentList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/paymentsTypeGV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnWidth="80dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
                android:numColumns="4"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="5dp"></GridView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

my problem is from my xml design and if i is from xml design the problem is in the parent list item ot the child list item or from the main XML File sorry if any thing is not clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a thought: try removing any padding on the text elements.

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

If this works, then this answer will become duplicate to:

[Android: TextView: Remove spacing and padding on top and bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768738/android-textview-remove-spacing-and-padding-on-top-and-bottom)

Comment: thanks alot for your Interests but i tried to put this in the recyclerView in XML file it's doesn't work