# TextView gravity bottom not working

Tags: android, textview, gravity

I have a simple LinearLayout and I try to make it looks like this:
[image: look2]

Instead it looks like:
[image: look1]

My xml is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="miasto"
            android:textSize="10sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ulica"
            android:textSize="15sp"           
            android:gravity="bottom"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="22"
        android:gravity="bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Why gravity="bottom" doesn't work?

Comment: The answer is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768738/android-textview-remove-spacing-and-padding-on-top-and-bottom

Answer (score 0):

You set this text view a width of `wrap_content` it means, what ever the text is, the view take the size of the text and for `LinearLayout` , the default gravity is `center`

Thus, Change

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Meanwhile, just for your information, `gravity` is the way the text will align itself in the `TextView`. The `TextView` being in `wrap_content` does nothing, as the TextView is exactly the size of the text.

`layout_gravity` is the way the `TextView` will align itself in its parent, in your case in the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Am I missing something? The TextView on the right has match_parent height. And I know the difference between layout gravity and gravity. If text_size is the same - both bottom textviews are int th same line, but if not...

Comment: That is because you have `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for the `LinearLayout`. Change that to `match_parent` and see if it works..

Comment: I know something about Android and I spent few hours trying to understand this. Of course I've tested many configurations. None of them is working. Please paste working code if you have some.

Answer (score -1):

Try to make your textview height match_parent.