# How do I remove default padding on textView?

Tags: android, textview, padding

So, this question is a duplicate, but the answers I have read doesn't work for me. If fact, they don't seem to have worked for other people either, so I'll give it another shot and see if someone knows the answer.

When Adding a textView, it looks like [image: this]

As you can see there is definitely a lot of space between the blue layout-marking and the actual text. When placing one `textView` on top of another the space becomes quite noticeable. Note that this is after I have added the XML code lines:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

(Which works to a small extent) and:

```
android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
```

(Which is said to solve the problem according to other threads, but does nothing for me for some reason).

The full XML for my `textView` is:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/healthTextId"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
    android:text="Test"

    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorHealth"

    android:textSize="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

The problem persists on both default and custom fonts. Any ideas?

This is one of the threads I read that unfortunately didn't solve the issue for me: [Android: TextView: Remove spacing and padding on top and bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768738/android-textview-remove-spacing-and-padding-on-top-and-bottom)

Comment: If your font has it's own paddings, you may not remove it. Have you tried different fonts?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both custom and default fonts...

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is very annoyying. Even if you remove all paddings, the padding of the font itself remains. Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42569871/13485979). This is a good approach.

Answer (score -3):

Just `android:padding="0dp"` should work.