# How can I align the text inside the TextView container to the top?

Tags: android, textview

Good day.
Not a problem to align the text inside the `TextView` horizontally. But how can I press the text inside the `TextView` to the top? It is necessary to align the text to the top in two `TextViews` located near and with different text sizes inside.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: here the image]

**Addition:
android:includeFontPadding="false" does not solve the problem:**

[that's why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6mkY.png)

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Please show the code (layout.axml)

Comment: Sorry, added the layout's code

Comment: @AllanStark check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768738/android-textview-remove-spacing-and-padding-on-top-and-bottom

Comment: @AllanStark and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42569871/7666442

Comment: android:includeFontPadding="false"

Answer (score 3):

include that in your textviews:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Comment: I apologize, but it seems that this does not solve the problem - the small distance between the top of the text and the upper border of the container still remains. And this distance is proportional to the size of the text inside the container, so the gap for my two containers with different sizes of text inside will also be different.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily recommend it, but try adding a negative marginTop for the view and see what happens