# Android - Constraint Layout - Alignment of Text and Icon

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-view

first of all I am new to Android-Development.
My question is regards alignment of different views in Android Studio/Development.
Specifically the properly height-alignment of an icon and text.

[Icon-Text-Alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtvq3.png)

As you can see, I tried to align the text with the icon. However the result looks slightly different in the emulator.

Here is my .xml-file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="352dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        android:text="Dashboard"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView10"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My questions are:

**1.** How can i fix the alignment of these two views? 
**2.** Why is the result in the emulator different? 
**3.** Is there a best-practice to align views properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***So I dig into the alignment issue a little further and came up with a few "solutions". Generally speaking and to answer my questions the "Custom Toolbar" is not the right solution to align the views.***

The problem lies in the padding of fonts. Android take the whole view to align views and not as assumed the "text" only. Therefore the alignment looks off.

[Different paddings/fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DXfR.png)

1. *Poppinsmedium*: without padding
2. *Poppinsmedium*: with padding; normal state
3. *Android-Font*: with padding; normal state

The bottom-padding can be eliminated with the following code:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Or check this thread for more in-depth knowledge of the [issues of font-padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768738/android-textview-remove-spacing-and-padding-on-top-and-bottom).

To align views, now I am using **Chain-Constraints** and do it without padding. It looks like the best-way to align views, especially Text-Views. However, I have to say that despite the deleting of the bottom padding it is necessary to adjust the alignment a littlebit with the vertical-bias.

For reference:

[constraintlayout.com](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html)

[Android-Doc: constrain-chain](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-chain)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="352dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        android:text="Dashboard"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="30sp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView10" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/imageView10"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Same problem occurs. In the emulator it looks again a little off.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by using a ***custom toolbar*** and adding a menu to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Custom toolbar` :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".terminalShortActivity">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#4EACE2"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Terminal Shortcuts"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```