# Android TextView separation inside layout problem

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout

i need to add two text views to a linear layout, the problem is that sometimes, depending on font size, an strange spacing appears in the middle, and i don't want it there.

Here is a screenshot:
[Text views in linear layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSWTO.png)

You can see that the first and second textview are perfectly aligned, but the second and third are not.

Why is this happening?

Here's the test xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Edit: Suggested question seems to refer to the same problem, however the proposed solutions don't fix my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: TextView: Remove spacing and padding on top and bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768738/android-textview-remove-spacing-and-padding-on-top-and-bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Add in your textView . It will removed extra padding

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView8"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView9"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This fixes some cases, but generates other ones.

Comment: generates what issues?

Comment: They are not lining, but worse, their bounds are overlapping https://imgur.com/a/wXdTvj4

Comment: I have updated answer and checked also seems working fine at zoom 300%

Comment: If i change the first's textSize to 26sp (for example) it starts to break.