# How to proper align custom font in an android app

Tags: android, android-studio, androiddesignsupport

I was trying google fonts to use in my android mobile application. I've noticed that when I used custom font, the center alignment to element (EditText, Button) has bigger space at the bottom. Tried `lineSpacingMultiplier` and `lineSpacingExtra` but it doesn't work. If I turned back to default Roboto font it works just fine.

[image]

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_phone"
        android:layout_width="300sp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="296dp"
        android:autofillHints="@string/label_phone"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
        android:hint="@string/label_phone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:maxLength="11"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

// custom_input
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:color="@color/colorSecondary"
        android:width="2sp" />
    <corners android:radius="10sp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="10sp"
        android:left="10sp"
        android:right="10sp"
        android:top="10sp" />
</shape>
```

I suspect that it has something to do with the font but I need to make the font input bigger so I specified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further research, this solved my issue,

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Ref: [Android: TextView: Remove spacing and padding on top and bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768738/android-textview-remove-spacing-and-padding-on-top-and-bottom)