# TextView height is different depending on text when textSize it's the same. Why?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-view, layoutparams

I noticed, that a TextView with the same textSize can have a different height depending on the String it is displaying.

I disscovered it when paiting a simple TableLayout which has some TableRow items with some cells, each cell is a TextView.

Those cells doesn't have top margin, and they are being painted perfectly in Android 8.0 and upper devices, **but in Android 7.0 and lower versions, some of the cells are adding a top margin between them, and this is because the height of the TextView is different.** I can't understand how is that happening, it's very frustrating.

In this case, it's happening in the TextView called `player` and only when the name is too much long and it's using ellipsize to truncate it.

The code is very simple:

```
public void populateGoalscorersTable(ArrayList<Player> players){
    goalscorersTableLayout.removeAllViews();

    for (int i=0; i<players.size() && i<30; i++){
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(goalscorersRowParams);

        TextView position = new TextView(this);
        position.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        position.setLayoutParams(goalscorersPositionParams);
        position.setText(""+(i+1));
        position.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_cell_background);
        position.setMinHeight((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cell_height));
        row.addView(position);

        TextView player = new TextView(this);
        player.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        player.setLayoutParams(goalscorersPlayerParams);
        player.setText(players.get(i).getName());
        player.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_cell_background);
        player.setMaxLines(1);
        player.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        player.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_small),0,(int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_small),0);
        player.setMinHeight((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cell_height));
        row.addView(player);

        TextView team = new TextView(this);
        team.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        team.setLayoutParams(goalscorersTeamParams);
        team.setText(players.get(i).getTeam().getName());
        team.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_cell_background);
        team.setMaxLines(1);
        team.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        team.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_small),0, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_small),0);
        team.setMinHeight((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cell_height));
        row.addView(team);

        TextView goals = new TextView(this);
        goals.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        goals.setLayoutParams(goalscorersPositionParams);
        goals.setText(""+players.get(i).getLeagueGoals());
        goals.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_cell_background);
        goals.setMinHeight((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cell_height));
        row.addView(goals);

        if (players.get(i).getTeam() == Manager.getInstance().getTeam()){
            player.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.player_team));
            player.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

            team.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.player_team));
            team.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }

        goalscorersTableLayout.addView(row);
    }
}
```

It's not the only way to make this errorneal top margin appearing (caused by a incorrect text height), I can see it for example when i have a row whith TextView cells with only one character and others with more than one character. The TextViews with more characters get's the margin. Also i can see this error happening when some TextViews are aligned to left and others centered. Very frustrating.

How can this be avoided?

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768738/android-textview-remove-spacing-and-padding-on-top-and-bottom

Comment: @Pawel checking that post I disscovered that if I put android:includeFontPadding to false and maxLines to 1, the problem is solved, but then, the text is not center vertically, is too much aligned to up, so android:includeFontPadding  seems to be necessary to get a centered text...

Answer (score 0):

If the font is not monospaced, different text can have different sizes and needs of space for letters that venture down the line such as j or p or q.

Comment: In monospaced fonts each character has the same width. It doesn't affect the height.