# Background color is applied in the whole line

Tags: android, android-activity, colors

I want the background color (blue) to be applied only where I have letters. Check the image below

[Click here to see the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T92I5.png)

[Not aligned to the right example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl97U.png)

Answer (score 1):

Set layout width to wrap content

Comment: ty! it solved the problem but then i have another problem which is that the text is alligned to the left. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768738/android-textview-remove-spacing-and-padding-on-top-and-bottom -> is says that i shall use match parent but that is the oppsosite of the suggested solution. what shall i do?

Comment: set gravity Right on the linearLayout

Comment: works a bit better but not exactly.
my code looks like this:
    
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.ScrolledLinearLayout);
linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setLayoutParams(new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
textView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
check my 2nd picture above to see how it looks like

Comment: LinearLayout needs to match parent

Answer (score 0):

set `TextView` width as wrap content, then color will be only in text area