Make Android TextView layout take up all space
I am trying to create an android view that makes the font size as large as possible.
Things I have done:

I have read the documentation on TextView and autoSize.
I have checked the margin, and padding for the TextView elements
I have tried manually setting the android:textSize but that produces causes issues with the linear layout.

Below is the XML I have.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/statusColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/statusSize"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:text="DISCONNECTED"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/power_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="200sp"
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
        android:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:background="#C83030"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textColor="@color/speedColor"
        tools:text="24.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/speed_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/power_text"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="200sp"
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
        android:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:background="#FF9800"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textColor="@color/speedColor"
        tools:text="500.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lap_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/speed_text"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="200sp"
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
        android:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:gravity="top|end"
        android:textColor="@color/speedColor"
        tools:text="500.0" />
</LinearLayout>

This XML produces the below view:

I want as small gap as possible between the three text fields so that the text size is as large as possible.

android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
android:autoSizeMinTextSize="1sp"
android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20000sp"
android:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"

You can set autoSizeText in the following way. add this to your textview.
basically you set maxsize really big then set android:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp". it will automatically shrink the text size until it fits your textview

Thanks for that. I already have those properties and I still have some padding on the top and bottom of each text element. Adding android:includeFontPadding="false" helped but didn't completely fix the issue.

sorry. i didn't read the question carefully.
after searching for a while. i found You need CustomView.
1 user wrote customView for textView here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42569871/20536350

They are creared repo:https://github.com/SenhLinsh/NoPaddingTextView.
